# deny all by ip .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, deny

I've been attempting to restrict access to an internet connected apache instance. My router has a port forward to the machine that is running apache. Don't know if this makes a difference.

Anyway I want to restrict it to LAN access only for the moment, and I want to use htaccess so that later I can enable visitors based on specific IPs. It is a dev server that I want my clients to be able to remotely preview, but not anyone else.

I've tried the instructions here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php which explain to do this

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.1
```

In my .htaccess file, but this doesn't work, I can still access it from outside the lan. I'm trying it from my phone's 3g and it works.

If I change the order to something like

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1
```

(remove the comma) as per the apache docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow and the page still allows access on my phone and on the local.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of "error.log" so we can examine and pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Or the access log if there aren't any errors.  And don't "censor" any IP addresses if/when you do post them.  They are the most important bit of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `AllowOverride All` to make sure that your `.htaccess` is not ignored.

Comment: What config file should this be in?

Comment: The `<Directory>` directive for your `DocumentRoot` in the main config file `httpd.conf`.